# Flutter: How to prioritize displaying the image from Asset, if it can't be found, then display image from URL?

Tags: json, image, listview, flutter, dart

This is JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "United States",
    "image": {
      "imageResName": "us.png",
      "imageUrl": "https://www.countryflags.io/US/shiny/64.png"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "Germany",
    "image": {
      "imageResName": "de.png",
      "imageUrl": "https://www.countryflags.io/DE/shiny/64.png"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "image": {
      "imageResName": "gb.png",
      "imageUrl": "https://www.countryflags.io/GB/shiny/64.png"
    }
  }
]
```

In assets, I created 3 image files: "us.png", "de.png", "gb.png" and I have created a ListView to display data from the JSON file. So I want to set the following condition:

**1. Display images in assets of the same name as `imageResName` first
        (Ex. "us.png" with `country: United States`)

 2. In case the file "us.png" cannot be found in assets, then it will
        display from the image from
            `imageUrl`.**

This is main.dart file

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ask/country.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<List<Country>> getCountryFromJson(BuildContext context) async {
    String jsonString =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/country.json');
    List<dynamic> raw = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    return raw.map((e) => Country.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Country')),
            body: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: getCountryFromJson(context),
                    builder: (context, data) {
                      if (data.hasData) {
                        List<Country> countries = data.data;
                        return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: countries.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/${countries[index].image.imageResName}                                  
                                  // 1. Prioritize displaying image from Asset
                                  // 2. If it can't find then display image from url
                                  // NetworkImage(countries[index].image.imageUrl),
                                ),
                                title: Text(countries[index].country),
                              );
                            });
                      } else {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                    }))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Just use `FadeInImage` as the following:

```
FadeInImage(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage(localPath),
                    placeholder: NetworkImage(urlPath),
              ),
```

Make sure your `image:` is your local asset while the `placeholder:` is your remote image.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

create a variable

```
String localImage = "assets/images/1.jpg";
```

this your logic but you need to find a way to check if localImage exist in locally
i dont know how why you want to do that, thats why i cant tell what logic you need to use , but this is your solution

```
leading: CircleAvatar(
// localImage = "assets/images/1.jpg"
    backgroundImage: localImage != null ? AssetImage(localImage) :  NetworkImage(countries[index].image.imageUrl),),
```

Comment: I want that by default, users will still load images from assets to ensure speed and experience, but when I add a new country from JSON, they will still see images from http without having to update the app to get new assets file. I tried your way but it didn't work, I'm not sure if I did anything wrong, please check it for me, this is a screenshot [link](https://i.imgur.com/iJig2Zi.jpg)

Comment: You are close just make sure your assets folder exist and image inside it exists, that's  why it gives you an error it cant find the assets folder i dont see it also, the screenshot you provided not clear

Comment: I think it definitely found the assets folder because it still shows images "de.png" and "gb.png" from assets. I tried deleting the image "us.png" to see if it displayed NetworkImage but it didn't work. I have taken a clearer screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/mFY8Eqy.jpg), please check for me if I did wrong somewhere

Comment: in your assets i dont see us.png image your  localImage is not null it has a value of String like this localImage  = "assets/us.png" so you code is trying to find the string but it does not find it so it wont show it and because its not null it has a string it wont show the network image thats why i told you you need to create a logic to find out if  localImage is not null, try change String localImage; and it will work and load the network image because localImage; is null now

Comment: wow, until now I understood what you meant, I tried printing it to make sure it was `null `and it worked: D [link](https://i.imgur.com/nerJSqu.jpg). Thank you for your patience. One more question, if we do not use `null` to determine, is there any way that when `Unable to load assets: assets / us.png` then it will switch to `NetworkImage`?